# Admin panel Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

hello i try to create panel admin with laravel and i have error

AdminController.php

```
1 <?php
2
3 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
4
5 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
6 use Auth;
7 class AdminController extends Controller
8 {
9    public function login(Request $request)
10    {
11      if($request->isMethod('post')){
12          $data = $request->input();
13          if 14(Auth::attempt(['email'->$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1'])) {
                echo "Success"; die; 
            }else{
                echo "Failed"; die;
            }
        }
        return view('admin.admin_login');
    }
}
```

error in line 14 its writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo error of `->` in  your code Change this

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email'->$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1'])) 
{
}
```

To

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $data['email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1'])) 
{
}
```

Thanks